# Convert Object NSNumber back to Floatvalue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a randomSpeed variable, and I add those randomSpeeds every few seconds in an mutable array  like this ( as object ) .

```
NSNumber *randomSpeed = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(arc4random() % 12)-3];
[self.UfoSpeed addObject:randomSpeed];
```

Now I am getting the index of an Object of another array via 
 `NSUInteger fooIndex = [self.Ufos indexOfObject: ufo];`
and now I need the `randomSpeed` of the index of the Object I got before as a float to add it to another float later on.

For example I need:`temp = self.UfoSpeed[fooIndex];`
then i add `ufo.position.x + temp;`

But its not working like that because the randomSpeed is an object of NSNumber and not a float/int.

Comment: I have tried this :       float temp = [randomSpeed floatValue]; and this: 
float temp = self.UfoSpeed[fooIndex];

Comment: Instead of posting a comment, update your question with the code you actually tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `NSNumber` object to float like this `[num floatValue];`

Comment: float temp = [self.UfoSpeed[fooIndex] floatValue]; this is how I did it thanks